# Weird appearances in a node

Tags: feeds, nodes

For some reasons I have too weird appearances in a node.

1. A "Read more" button appearing near to my "Tags" list (even though my display settings dictate only "Full page" appearance, and I've disabled any other option.
2. An RSS button, that appears there although I never installed the Aggregator module.

How can you explain these phenomena?

Comment: It's probably something broken with your theme but we know nothing about your theme. Are you using one from drupal.org or a custom one?

Comment: Kind of custom one (Bootstrap business CSS-Customed).

Comment: Is it on node type page too ? I think you are checking node type article

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was some kind of data mixing made by mistake at the `page.tpl.php`.

I think it's fixed now.